# How to specify CMake variables when compiling libraries via vcpkg?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I want to install [libwebm](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm) library on my Windows computer with `vcpkg`. I need a specific module of that library named WebM Parser. It is excluded from the library by default; `CMake` `ENABLE_WEBM_PARSER` variable should be set to `ON` to include it. For example, that would be done by passing `-DENABLE_WEBM_PARSER:BOOL=ON` command option to `CMake`.
Package `libwebm:x64-windows` is available in `vcpkg`, but it lacks the module I need. How can I pass the variable or command option to `CMake` `vcpkg` uses?

I tried compiling the library by cloning it and using `Windows CMake GUI` with `Visual Studio`, but compilation fails with tons of errors. Moreover, it would be handier to me to get everything done by `vcpkg` to use its `CMake toolchain file` instead of linking manually.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve that:

a) Use an overlay port for libwebm passing the option `-DENABLE_WEBM_PARSER:BOOL=ON` via `vcpkg_cmake_configure` `OPTIONS` arguments

b) Use an overlay triplet and put the variable into `VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS` via `set(VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS -DENABLE_WEBM_PARSER:BOOL=ON)` within the triplet.